# Swift Perfect compile command failed for linux environment

Tags: swift, linux, docker, perfect

I'm trying to create on Swift Perfect project. I'm trying to send one response for a link. My class looks as follows

```
class Model: JSONConvertibleObject {

    static let registerName = "prospect"

    var userEmail = ""
    var authToken = ""
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
    var email = ""
    var countryCode = 0
    var phone = 0

    var mobile = 0
    var homeNo = 0
    var gender = ""
    var age = ""
    var martialStatus = ""
    var spiritualCondition = ""
    var language = ""
    var notes = ""

    let constants = SwConstants.JsonConstants()

    override func setJSONValues(_ values: [String : Any]) {
        self.firstName = getJSONValue(named: constants.firstName, from: values, defaultValue: "")
        self.lastName = getJSONValue(named: constants.lastName , from: values, defaultValue: "")
        self.email = getJSONValue(named: constants.email, from: values, defaultValue: "")
        self.countryCode = getJSONValue(named: constants.countryCode, from: values, defaultValue: 0)

        self.mobile = getJSONValue(named: constants.mobile, from: values, defaultValue: 0)
        self.homeNo = getJSONValue(named: constants.homeNo, from: values, defaultValue: 0)
        self.gender = getJSONValue(named: constants.email, from: values, defaultValue: "")
        self.age = getJSONValue(named: constants.age, from: values, defaultValue: "")
        self.language = getJSONValue(named: constants.language, from: values, defaultValue: "")
        self.spiritualCondition = getJSONValue(named: constants.spiritualCondition, from: values, defaultValue: "")


    }

    override func getJSONValues() -> [String : Any] {

        return [
            JSONDecoding.objectIdentifierKey:ProspectModel.registerName,
            constants.firstName:firstName,
            constants.lastName:lastName,
            constants.email: email,
            constants.countryCode :countryCode,
            constants.phone: phone,

            constants.mobile: mobile,
            constants.homeNo: homeNo,
            constants.gender:gender,
            constants.age:age,
            constants.martialStatus: martialStatus,
            constants.language:language,
            constants.spiritualCondition:spiritualCondition

        ]

    }

}
```

As soon as I added spiritualCondition and try compiling the build in Swift Asistant using Docker, MacOS build is building successfully. But, the linux build is giving error

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Killed
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Failed: systemError(1, "sh: no job control in this shell\n<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures\nswift-build: error: exit(1): /swift-3.0.2-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /perfectbuild/.build_lin/release.yaml\n")
```

Can anyone please explain me what the problem is? I am new to Swift Perfect. I'm not able to get verbose as well. It would be really helpful if anyone explain how to get build verbose.

Comment: Ah! No. If it had to, I should face even with few data.

Comment: Are you compiling this on a cloud server? Your application may have been killed because it was using too much memory while compiling. If this is the case you can fix it by enabling some swap space on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

first thing first, you should try Perfect Assistant 2 instead, it can now select Swift 3.1 or later version to compile in this app. Secondly, I have no idea about your "SwConstant" so I could not compile your code.

However, this snippet has been tested on both OS X & Linux by PA2:

```
import PerfectLib

class User: JSONConvertibleObject {
  static let registerName = "user"
  var firstName = ""
  var lastName = ""
  var age = 0
  override func setJSONValues(_ values: [String : Any]) {
    self.firstName = getJSONValue(named: "firstName", from: values, defaultValue: "")
    self.lastName = getJSONValue(named: "lastName", from: values, defaultValue: "")
    self.age = getJSONValue(named: "age", from: values, defaultValue: 0)
  }
  override func getJSONValues() -> [String : Any] {
    return [
      JSONDecoding.objectIdentifierKey:User.registerName,
      "firstName":firstName,
      "lastName":lastName,
      "age":age
    ]
  }
}

JSONDecoding.registerJSONDecodable(name: User.registerName, creator: {  return User() })

let user = User()
user.firstName = "Donnie"
user.lastName = "Darko"
user.age = 17

if let encoded = try? user.jsonEncodedString() {
  print(encoded)
  if let u = try? encoded.jsonDecode() as? User, let v = u {
    print(v.age, v.firstName, v.lastName)
  }
}
```

Good luck.